# Can anyone check my answers?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

This is about hypothesis testing.
Please check my answers
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution to part a) is right, but you did not complete the question on part b) yet. It is indeed true that the test statistic takes the value 3.16, but you have to give the probability of not rejecting the null hypothesis where you should.

You can do so by calculating: $\mathbb{P}[4.8387 \leq \bar{X} \leq 5.1613 | \mu = 4]$. Now, the distribution of $\bar{X}$ is $\mathcal{N}(4,\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}})$. So, we get:  $\mathbb{P}[4.8387 \leq \bar{X} \leq 5.1613 | \mu = 4] = 0.0387$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to (A) is just the 95% Probability Interval for the mean of a sample from a normal population with mean $\mu_0$. Your Z score looks incorrect as 0.51 corresponds to $Z_{0.69}$. $Z_{.025} \approx -1.96$ so you want the interval $\mu_0\pm \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n}$ Where $\mu_0 = 5$

Your answer for (b) is not a probability. You want $P(\mu_0 - \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n}\leq \bar X \leq \mu_0+\frac{1.96}{\sqrt n}) = P(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}(\mu_0 - \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n}-4)\leq Z \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n}(\mu_0 + \frac{1.96}{\sqrt n}-4))$ Where we now assume $\bar X$ has mean 4 not 5.

I'll leave the rest to you.